# Why are these lines of code in Pascal necessary?

Tags: function, repeat, pascal, ord

The following example in Pascal was given in a book dedicated to the basics of programming. The function *ReadLongint* is supposed to check whether the input is 0-9 encoded in a char type. The function then returns true or false depending on the check results, as well as a variable for calculations, rendered into an integer via the operator *ord()*.
Being a newbie I've had hard times figuring out how exactly this code works. But even the bigger mystery for me was the necessity of line 9.

```
    'repeat
         read(c);
         position := position + 1;
     until (c <> #32) and (c <> #10);'
```

I can see that it's a cycle which repeats itself if you input Space or Enter. However, I've checked the program without these lines, substituting it with a simple *read(c);* , and the program seems to work just fine. Can somebody please explain the role of this line in the example?

Here is the full program:

```
function ReadLongint(var check: longint): boolean;
     var
         c: char;
         number: longint;
         position: integer;
     begin
         number := 0;
         position := 0;
         repeat
             read(c);
             position := position + 1;
         until (c <> #32) and (c <> #10);
         while (c <> #32) and (c <> #10) do
         begin
             if (c < '0') or (c > '9') then
             begin
                 writeln('Unexpected ''', c, ''' in position: ', position);
                 readln;
                 ReadLongint := false;
                 exit
             end;
             number := number * 10 + ord(c) - ord('0');
             read(c);
             position := position + 1
         end;
         check := number;
         ReadLongint := true
     end;
var
    x, y: longint;
    ok: boolean;
begin
    repeat
        write('Please type the first number: ');
        ok := ReadLongint(x)
    until ok = true;
    repeat
        write('Please type the second number: ');
        ok := ReadLongint(y)
    until ok = true;
    writeln(x, ' times ', y, ' is ', x * y)
end.
```

Comment: _"and the program seems to work just fine"_ Does it still do what it's supposed to though? What do you end up with in `x` if you enter 123?

Comment: @Michael Yes, the results are the same. At least I don't see any error

Comment: Ah, right, it just discard leading spaces and newlines. So the original code would allow you to write multiple spaces in front of the first digit.

Comment: @Michael  Oh, haven't seen this one. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Michael One more thing: when those lines are absent ('read(c)' instead) and I hit space and enter it goes like this: ''Please enter the first number: <space><enter> ... Please enter the second number: 0 times 0 is 0'' What's happening here? I understand that ASCII code of <space> is saved thus bypassing the whole function, but what about <enter> and why ''Please enter the second number: 0 times 0 is 0'' displays the result of the multiplication before the vesry las 'writeln()' starts?

Comment: Look at the condition for the second loop (the one that actually reads the digits), and consider what `c` might contain if you replace the first loop with just a `read`. Step through the code in a debugger if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your `readLongInt` function wants to (partially) mimic the behavior of `read`/`readLn`. The behavior of `read`/`readLn` differs slightly if the destination variable is an `integer` (or `real`) or `char` value. The [ISO Standard 7185](http://www.pascal-central.com/iso7185.html#6.9.1%20The%20procedure%20read) puts it like that:

> c) If `v` is a *variable-access* possessing the *`integer`-type* (or subrange thereof), `read(f, v)` shall satisfy the following requirements. No component of *s* shall equal *end‑of‑line*. The components of *r*, if any, shall each, and *(s ~t ~u).first* shall not, equal either the *`char`-type* value space or end‑of‑line. […]

Translated to plain English: Leading spaces and newlines are ignored *when* interpreting *a number* (i. e. an `integer` [or `real`] variable as the destination). This is quite different to  `read`/`readLn` in conjunction with a `char`‑variable where `' '` is a *legal* value, thus it is *not* “skipped”, you know.

The `until (c <> #32) and (c <> #10)` loop is trying to imitate the behavior of `read(check)` although the actually used `read(c)` merely reads a single `char` value, one after another.

PS: It always makes me cringe seeing `ok = true`. I hope *you*, unlike the author(s) of the textbook, knows that the `= true` is redundant, merely an identity.